# Will I have to do any update or upgrade at the release date of the Windows 8 OS?

Tags: windows-8, license

I'm a MSDN subscriber and I would like to download and setup Windows 8 (x64) (legally of course) on my computer. The question I currently asking myself is the following :

**Will I have to do any update or upgrade at the release date of the OS ?**

Because I don't want to install all drivers, softwares and co. if I'll have to format my hard disk and reinstall the "official" released OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an MSDN subscriber, you have access to the RTM version of the OS. This is exactly the same as the version that will be released to consumers in October. There will not be any further upgrades required when the consumer release date arrives. There may be updates, but those will just be typical Windows updates, no reinstalling of the OS.

For further explanation, see this article on the [RTM release of Windows](http://www.theverge.com/2012/8/15/3243935/windows-8-download-msdn-technet-subscribers).